# Iterate a function over files in a dir and save resultant files in another dir

Tags: python, loops, iteration

Hello experts and lovely people on the internet!
I have this python script running for one image. It is a bmp image, and i would like to change it to another color map, and perform some color analysis.

Here is the [image.](https://ibb.co/HB7pP0L)

To change the existing image to another color map, I use this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image

def pil_test():
    cm_nippy = mpl.cm.get_cmap('nipy_spectral')
    img_src = Image.open('oldpath\\oldimage.bmp').convert('L')
    img_src.thumbnail((425,290))
    im = np.array(img_src)
    im = cm_nippy(im)
    im = np.uint8(im * 255)
    im = Image.fromarray(im)
    im.save('newpath\\newimagename.bmp')
```

I would like it to run through all the images in a dir 'oldpath' and save the new images in a new folder/dir. I have similar such small scripts which does color analysis, such as looking at the 5 most dominant colors in this image.

```
import cv2, numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import os

def visualize_colors(cluster, centroids):
    # Get the number of different clusters, create histogram, and normalize
    labels = np.arange(0, len(np.unique(cluster.labels_)) + 1)
    (hist, _) = np.histogram(cluster.labels_, bins = labels)
    hist = hist.astype("float")
    hist /= hist.sum()

    # Create frequency rect and iterate through each cluster's color and percentage
    rect = np.zeros((50, 300, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    colors = sorted([(percent, color) for (percent, color) in zip(hist, centroids)])
    start = 0
    for (percent, color) in colors:
        print(color, "{:0.2f}%".format(percent * 100))
        end = start + (percent * 300)
        cv2.rectangle(rect, (int(start), 0), (int(end), 50), \
                      color.astype("uint8").tolist(), -1)
        start = end
    return rect

# Load image and convert to a list of pixels
image = cv2.imread('path\\image.bmp')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
reshape = image.reshape((image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], 3))


# Find and display most dominant colors
cluster = KMeans(n_clusters=5).fit(reshape)
visualize = visualize_colors(cluster, cluster.cluster_centers_)
visualize = cv2.cvtColor(visualize, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imshow('visualize', visualize)


path = 'newpath\\'
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, 'visualise.bmp'), visualize)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This gives an image [like this](https://ibb.co/D9Vxxy3)
and an output such as:

[9.86020733e+01 7.56017471e-12 1.22927118e+02] 12.76%

[  4.70891972  18.53593429 199.90143737] 16.20%

[ 2.35389600e+02  1.72190556e+02 -2.84217094e-14] 18.83%

[4.26325641e-13 1.51154637e+02 1.86175066e+02] 22.70%

[  6.49062069 200.6777931    6.82637241] 29.51%

I would like to have both of these run one after the other in sequence or individually for all the images in my folder dir, and save them in another folder.

At the moment I am trying the following. Unfortunately this is not working!

```
# import required module
import os
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

# assign directory
directory = 'old path'
new_path = 'new path'

from PIL import Image

def pil_test():
    cm_nippy = mpl.cm.get_cmap('nipy_spectral')
    img_src = Image.open('directory').convert('L')
    img_src.thumbnail((425,290))
    im = np.array(img_src)
    im = cm_nippy(im)
    im = np.uint8(im * 255)
    im = Image.fromarray(im)
    im.save('new_path')


 
# iterate over files in
# that directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    # checking if it is a file and calling the function above
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        pil_test(f)
```

Which gives me an error "TypeError: pil_test() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

HELP!

Answer (score 0):

You define `def pil_test()` without any arguments. Then tyou are trying to use it with an argument `(f)`. Of course, you get an error.
Rewrite your function `pill_test()` with an argument passed into it (like a filename/filepath), then try your code again.

Comment: I did not get what you mean by without any arguments.

Comment: You defined it as `pil_test()` then tried to use it as `pil_test(f)` - f is the argument. You should define the function with an argument, use that argument in the function logic, and then you can call it with an argument.